# JavaScript for auto embedding image URL works but getting W3 errors

Tags: javascript, jquery, w3c-validation, oembed

I now where my errors are, I just don't know enough about javascript know where it needs to go, can anyone help me. I finally got this all working to auto embed media and images on my site (phpbb forum), and it works good, but the image embed isn't correct (even though it does work).

Here's my errors from W3:

required attribute "src" not specified

required attribute "alt" not specified

document type does not allow element "img" here

end tag for "img" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified

So obviously I did a number on the code, but somehow it's managing to function.

Here's my hack job of a code, can anyone help me clean this mess? (I'm just a newbie, this was the best I could come up with after hours and hours);

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".content1 .postlink").oembed(null, {embedMethod: "append", maxWidth: 300,});
    });
})(jQuery);

$(document).ready(function () {
    var href = $('a.postlink.img-link').get(0).href;
    $('a.postlink.img-link').html($('').attr('src', href).fadeIn(1000));
    $('a.postlink.img-link').colorbox({rel: 'img-link'});
})
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code could use some tidying up, but we would need to see the relevant HTML to really help you tidy it up.

You probably want to change

```
$('a.postlink.img-link').html($('').attr('src', href).fadeIn(1000));
```

to

```
$('a.postlink.img-link img').attr('src', href)
```

as a start.

However, to answer your main question about the W3 validator, looks at the page before any javascript has run.  So I am assuming that you have `<img>` tags with no src attribute (looks like this is getting set by the javascript).  These are the sort of errors that the validator is complaining about.

A HTML page should really 'work' correctly even if javascript is disabled.  Even if this just means showing placeholder content or a message saying that javascript is required.

To fix the validation errors, add src and alt attributes to the img tags in your html, point them at some sort of placeholder images and text that is representative of the actual content that will be replaced by your JS.

This should also help in the visual rendering of your page.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  When I replace that line, the embed function no longer works, I just get the link instead of the image.

Comment: Here is an example of the html <!-- m --><a class="postlink img-link" href="http://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/49c5e8ca3322a29b74978eae4b0a34ff58d50ae0/c=160-0-2984-2123&amp;r=x408&amp;c=540x405/local/-/media/2015/11/21/DetroitFreePress/DetroitFreePress/635837246053031811-AP-Raiders-Browns-Football-C.jpg" rel="nofollow" onclick="this.target='_blank';">http://www.gannett-cdn.com/-mm-/49c5e8c ... ball-C.jpg</a><!-- m -->

Comment: And I apologize for all the messages, I'm new to this format and every time I hit enter I submit LOL.  Basically, it's just the that line of html which is causing the errors in W3, and is definitely from the JS code I added because if I remove it, it's all fine.

Comment: ok, that was just a guess.  Would need to see the full HTML you are trying to manipulate. In the above example there is no img tag which tells me that there is some other javascript magic going on there.  If you are using some sort of framework, your questions might be better directed to a dedicated list for that framework.

Comment: The people at phpbb are very particular about helping re: items which aren't supported modifications.  This was one I was trying to figure out myself because I've been trying to learn some more things to be able to go beyond what's available.  Here's a link a post  where the problem will occur:  https://raiderforums.com/viewtopic.php?t=8910&p=333253#p333253

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> //<![CDATA[
    // [your script here]
// ]]></script>
```